# Create a Query in Access which just lists the rows with the most recent entries/dates

Tags: date, ms-access, filter, group-by, max

I have a table that lists people's names. Every time their score is updated, a new row is created with their name and the date the score was updated, along with their new score.

```
Name    Date     Score
James   5/10/18  100
Edward  5/10/18  50
James   1/11/18  200
Edward  1/11/18  140
Eleanor 5/10/18  80
```

I need a query that will list the current scores like the table below.

```
Name     Score
James    200
Edward   140
Eleanor  80
```

I've tried grouping the fields and then setting the date to Max in the totals field of the query table but it keeps listing all the results. I've tried looking it up but I think my technical knowledge on how best to word this question is giving me problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Just a self-join to the same table using two aliases.

```
  SELECT t1.*
  FROM myTable AS t1 LEFT JOIN myTable AS t2
  ON (t1.Name  = t2.Name  AND t1.Date < t2.Date)
  WHERE t2.Date IS NULL;
```